# What does the STICKY_TIMEOUTS flag for personality(2) do?

Tags: system-calls, system-programming

Is there a good description of exactly what each of the flags you can pass to `personality(2)` does? I'm particularly interested in `STICKY_TIMEOUTS`, but a general detailed description of all of them would be nice.

I've googled a bunch for this and can't find it. And I like knowing these things.

This is a very specific programming question, but it's also very Unix/Linux specific. I wasn't sure if it should go here or on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man 2 personality`:

> STICKY_TIMEOUTS (since Linux 1.2.0)
>
> With this flag set, select(2), pselect(2), and ppoll(2) do not modify the returned  time‐out argument when interrupted by a signal handler.

You can read the rest of the man page for detailed descriptions of each of the available flags.

Comment: I managed to figure that out by finding a kernel source commit that mentioned STICKY_TIMEOUTS. Ubuntu 16.04's version of this manpage does not have this information or I wouldn't have asked the question. Fedora 26's does. I wonder why.

Comment: I think it's because Fedora's man pages are 4 months newer than Ubuntu's (2016-03-15 vs. 2015-12-28).

Comment: On which distribution did you find this man page?

Comment: I found it on Arch Linux.

Comment: The information only landed in the upstream man page in Jan 2016, which probably explains why it is not in Ubuntu 16.04 man pages.